# Google Query Spreadsheet: reverse transpose

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have this table (as an example)

```
id  |  a   |   b  |  c 
1   |  23  |   13 |  56 
2   |  67  |  45  |
3   |  43  |      |
4   |  78  |  34  |  45
```

I want to upload transpose that using the query statement so that I can upload it to my database, the result should look like:

```
1 | 23
1 | 13
1 | 56
2 | 67
2 | 45
3 | 43
4 | 78
4 | 34
4 | 45
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data in A:D, try:

```
=ArrayFormula({transpose(split(query(rept(A:A&" ", if(len(B:B), countif(if(not(isblank(B:D)), row(B:B)), row(B:B)),)),,50000)," ")),transpose(split(join(" ",query(transpose(B:D),,50000)), " "))})
```